# Fedora 8: rubygems.org certificate validation failure. How to install GeoTrust CA?

Tags: linux, fedora, ssl, certificate

Trying to get a gem:

```
$gem install puppet
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'puppet' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I looked at the certificate used by rubygems.org:

```
$openssl s_client -showcerts -connect rubygems.org:443 
...
Certificate chain
0 s:/serialNumber=RRAXldgzDrRZWQpGo6FHdTHV3qwvwXtD/OU=GT35895174/OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)13/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=*.rubygems.org
  i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
...
1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA
  i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
...
```

So I downloaded the GeoTrust CA:

```
$wget http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root_certificates/certificates/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
```

And now I'm left with the last task, install this CA. But I can't find the proper way to do it. Specifically, using [`certutil`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/NSS_Tools_:_certutil) as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Certificate_System/8.1/html/Admin_Guide/Managing_the_Certificate_Database.html#Installing_Certificates_through_the_Console):

```
$cd /var/lib/instance_name/alias
$certutil -A -n cert-name -t trustargs -d . -a -i certificate_file
```

My old Fedora 8 system does not have a `/var/lib/instance_name/alias` 'subsystem security database directory' and I really failed at locating one.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `ca-certificates` (via `sudo yum install ca-certificates`)? If it is installed, you could try reinstalling it.